# Add Local group restrictions with cmd

Tags: google-chrome, cmd, windows-7, gpo

How I could add **Additional Rules in Software Restriction Policies** with cmd using a script that'll work with ***both Windows 7 and Windows Vista***.

I would like to create some path rules with security level set to "**Disallowed**".

Below are a few lines I'd like to incorporate into this script:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Chrome.exe
chrome_installer.exe
Gears-chrome-opt.msi
GoogleUpdate.exe
```

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: Crossposted to [su]. [Add Local group restrictions with cmd](http://superuser.com/q/1100828)